# How can I read Integers separated by newLine using Stream?

Tags: java, stream

I want to read multiple Integers seperated by newLines using Stream. I definitely know how to do it with a Scanner but I try to figure out Streams.
My Input will be a number of Integers, the first Integer n will decide how many Lines are to follow.

> 5
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5

I am confused about the purpose of the InputStreamReader. 
Can I use it to read Input from the user? It does have the method read and an overloaded version of it. I thought I could use the overloaded method to save the values into an array and then, sum them up, find the average and whatever. But this

```
try(InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in)){
        int n = isr.read();
        int count =0;
        isr.read(char[] cbuf, 0, n);

    }
```

is not working. As you can probably figure, I am entirely new to streams. Usually I get along with the book I'm reading (Ivor Horton "Beginning Java"), the java docs and stuff that other people have asked here, but not this time. I've been unable to find proper tutorials or anything, probably because I dont  know what my exact question is. 
I'd appreciate any explanaitons but helpful links or literature as well.
Louis

Comment: How about using a `Scanner` instead?

Comment: Each call to `isr.read()` give you just one letter, where the number is the ASCII or Unicode of the character entered.  In short this is a very low level interface which is probably not worth using unless it is just for interest sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) which gives you `readLine()` method similar to `Scanner.nextLine()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        System.out.println(n);
        while (n-- > 0) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 2 Questions:
1. readLine() will return a String. To use Stream to do further calculations with the numbers wouldnt it be preferable to return a Stream?
2. Is Buffered reader just changing the characterStream of InputStreamReader to text? So it just makes everything easier to handle?